# Make androids "wave" effect in blender

Tags: animation, materials

I want to make an animation of a wave like the following images:
[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

I want to achieve that same transparent material. As you can see they are two waves, one over the other. One wave is dark gray, and the other one is light gray. I want these two waves to move the opposite waves, like one moves to the right and the other one moves the the left and then return to the start point in a "smooth" way and repeat. I only need the guide on how to make the animation, the materials are not a problem. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a simple plane with some modifiers? I have added a Subdivision + Wave modifier, then added a Solidify modifier to give it thickness.

[image: modifiers wave]

Then I changed the camera to Orthographic to shoot only the wave part.

[image: wave camera]